# The two planes 2x-y+3z=2 and -4x+2y-6z=3 are parallel. Let V= the set of P1P2: P1 is an element of equations one and P2 is an element of equation 2.

Tags: linear-algebra

The two planes 2x-y+3z=2 and -4x+2y-6z=3 are parallel. Let V= the set of P1P2: P1 is an element of equations one and P2 is an element of equation 2. Is this a vector space?
P1P2 should have a line above them.

my real issue is understanding what makes them parallel and how when i test the axioms i can tell if the answer i have gotten is in fact part of V so i can prove or fail the axiom

Answer (score 1):

They are parallel because their normal vectors are in the same vector space (they are a linear combination of each other). These vectors are $\langle 2,-1,3\rangle$ for the first plane, and $\langle -4,2,-6\rangle$ for the second plane.

Since $V=\left\{\overrightarrow{P_1P_2}:P_1\text{ is in the first plane and }P_2\text{ is in the second plane}\right\}$ is there a way in which $\overrightarrow{P_1P_2}=\mathbf 0$? Or more simply, are there $P_1,P_2\colon P_1=P_2$? Or even simpler, do the planes intersect?

Comment: So as long as its a formula of (2(x), -1(y), 3(z)) it would be part of the vector?

Comment: and how would you test if they intersect or not? Im very rusty on work with planes

Comment: @becca the planes are parallel, so if they intersect they have to intersect in all their points, i.e. they have to be the same plane. Our intuition says that the planes aren't the same. So there must be a reason for which the planes can't be the same; in fact, multiply the first equation by 2 and then add the result to the equation of the second plane. You should end up with $0=7$ which is a contradiction, hence the planes are different.

Comment: @becca I didn't understand your first question :( can you rephrase it to make it clearer?

Comment: i realize that first question actually makes no sense now you can ignore it haha. And since the planes are different it must mean it fails at an axiom probably A1 or M1 since i was told you can probably use the subset theorem. is showing they arnt on the same plane one of them?

Comment: lets say i looked at M1 where k(2,-1,3) (or even could i do that as a proof? I'm only really familiar with Rn versions) at k=2 gives you (4,-2,6) and so P1P2 (line) would be (0,0,0) although i dont know exactly how that disproves it like is that not in the vector space or not?

Comment: @becca as the planes don't intersect, then there aren't $P_1,P_2$ such that $\overrightarrow{P_1P_2}=\mathbf 0$. And if the zero vector is not in $V$ then $V$ can't be a vector space! :D